# Missing delimiter error?

Tags: errors, delimiters, multline

I use the following codes with **Winedt5.5** and **Miktek2.8** :

```
\documentclass{amsart}[12pt]

\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amscd, amssymb, amsfonts}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{multline*}
|\frac{e}{e-1}(e^z-1)|\leq \frac{1}{2}e^{|z|}+ (1-\mu )e^{|z|}-1 +\frac{\mu\pi}{\pi^2 -1} \sinh(\pi|z|) +\frac{\mu}{\pi^2-1} (\cosh(\pi|z|)-1)
\\
\leq \frac{1}{2} e^{|z|} + (1-\mu )(e^{|z|}-1 )+\frac{\mu}{\pi-1}\sinh(\pi|z|)
 \\
\leq \frac{\pi-2}{2\pi}e^{|z|}+\frac{1}{\pi-1}(e^{\pi|z|}-1)
\\
 \leq  \left \frac{2}{\pi-1}(e^{\pi|z|}-1)
\end{multline*}

\end{document}
```

But I faced to the following errors:

> **Missing delimiter error <.inserted>.**
>
> **< to be read again >**
>
> **1.15 \end < multline* >**

Can someone help me to improve the problem?
Thanks.

Comment: The `\left` directive in the final row before `\end{multline*}` would look to be superfluous.

Comment: You need to put a delimiter after the `\left`, such as `\left*(`, on the third last line -- and then you will need a matching `\right)`.

Comment: Off-topic: You may want to look into updating your TeX distribution. MikTeX2.8 hasn't been updated in several years. Do yourself a favor and download and install MikTeX2.9.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `\left` directive in the row immediately before `\end{multline*}` doesn't look like it's needed. If it's omitted, the error message goes away. Note that `\left` and `\right` need to be followed either by a "delimiter" -- such as `(`,  `[`, `)`, and `]` -- or by a `.` ("period", "full stop").

I would also recommend you look into using an `align*` environment instead of a `multline*` environment.

A full MWE (with a pair round parentheses added in the first row, a macro called `\abs` defined via `\DeclarePairedDelimiter`, and the document class option `12pt` repositioned):

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{mathtools, amsthm, amscd, amssymb, amsfonts}
\usepackage{environ}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{\lvert}{\rvert}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\abs[\Big]{\frac{e}{e-1}(e^z-1)}
&\leq \frac{1}{2}e^{\abs{z}} + (1-\mu)(e^{\abs{z}}-1) % w/ extra parens
      + \frac{\mu\pi}{\pi^2-1} \sinh(\pi\abs{z}) 
      + \frac{\mu}{\pi^2-1} (\cosh(\pi\abs{z})-1) \\
&\leq \frac{1}{2}e^{\abs{z}} + (1-\mu)(e^{\abs{z}}-1 )
      + \frac{\mu}{\pi-1}\sinh(\pi\abs{z}) \\
&\leq \frac{\pi-2}{2\pi}e^{\abs{z}}
      + \frac{1}{\pi-1}(e^{\pi\abs{z}}-1) \\
&\leq \frac{2}{\pi-1}(e^{\pi\abs{z}}-1)
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```